# Returning falsy values in javascript instead of true/false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the best practice in javascript when a function is supposed to return true or false? Can I return falsy values directly instead of true or false?
I found this code:

```
function supportsAPL(handlerInput) {
  const supportedInterfaces = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces;
  const aplInterface = supportedInterfaces['Alexa.Presentation.APL'];
  return aplInterface != null && aplInterface !== undefined;
}
```

and simplified it to this code:

```
function supportsAPL(handlerInput) {
   const {supportedInterfaces} = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.device;
   return supportedInterfaces['Alexa.Presentation.APL'];
}
```

which works but I'm not sure this is proper/nice javascript. I'm looking for what an experienced javascript developer would write after finding the 1st code snippet (also looking to save lines of code).

Comment: You could coerce the value into a real Boolean with `return !!supportedInterfaces['Alexa.Presentation.APL']`

Comment: It totally depends upon what the caller of the function expects or what the doc says the function will return.  If the function documents that it returns a Boolean, then it should return `true` or `false`.  If the function documents that it returns a any truthy or falsey value, then it can do that and the caller should act accordingly.  If I were designing an API, whose main job was to deliver a Boolean result, I'd make sure it returned an actual Boolean (`true` or `false`) - just less chance for anyone to ever get confused at minimal cost to make that happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the 'best practice' is to always return what the caller's are going to use it for. So, in this case, the function is named **supportsAPL** which seems like it should return a yes / no (`true` / `false`) to let the caller know that whatever input you gave the function supports APL or not.

You mentioned that you simplified this:

```
return aplInterface != null && aplInterface !== undefined;
```

to be this:

```
return supportedInterfaces['Alexa.Presentation.APL'];
```

In this case, we went from returning a specific true / false to returning whatever the value of `supportedInterfaces['Alexa.Presentation.APL'];` is. If APL is supported, you're going to get the value of `supportedInterfaces['Alexa.Presentation.APL'];` whereas if it's not supported, you'll likely get a falsy value of `undefined`

More than likely, the caller is going to be doing something like this:

```
if (supportsAPL(input)) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
const aplSupported = supportsAPL(input);
if (aplSupported) {
    ....
}
```

But, if you are only returning truthy falsy, you're going to break anybody who was expecting a boolean return. So these won't work:

```
if (supportsAPL(input) === true) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
const aplSupported = supportsAPL(input);
if (aplSupported === true) {
    ....
}
```

In my opinion, always return a boolean in these scenarios since that's the main point of the function (to determine if whatever the input is supports APL).

As @Phil mentioned,

```
return aplInterface != null && aplInterface !== undefined;
```

can be simplified to this:

```
return !!supportedInterfaces['Alexa.Presentation.APL']
```